# What is a "CFG" application in GIS terminology probably?

Tags: 3d, terrain

I come across a 2008 tech presentation PDF on "GIS-Enabled Modeling and Simulation (GEMS) presented by ESRI (i think for the US Army).
On one of the page titled "Challenges to be overcomed", there is this point:

```
> 3D Visualisation:
>    GIS data is inherently 2D
>      Fine for CGF Applications
>    ArcGlobe
>    Procedural terrain visualization approaches.
```

I believe this point is saying that 2D visualisation is OK for CFG applications, but for their puporse 3D should be used.

Anyone can tell what "CGF Applications" mean?

[edit: deleted second question]

Thanks for any help.

PS: I know it's ESRI sales team job to answer these questions, but I am just a student doing research on terrain rendering. Don't think they will entertain me.

EDIT: typo corrected from CFG to CGF.

Comment: How about putting your second question into a new separate question?

Comment: hi underdark, well.... I think I shall delete the second question. because knowing what CGF is is sufficient for my purpose. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computer Generated Forces for your first question.

Comment: Hi GuillaumeC, Eventhough I had the typo in the acronym you managed to get it. Many thanks.